# Provided dependency in library, using previous version in project

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependency-management

If a library declares *provided* dependency on eg **servlet-api** using v3.0.1; would it be possible for users to use version 2.5 for their library, that will be used on third party web application?

In other words:

```
mylib (srv 3.0.1)  <-- some_framework(srv 2.5)  <--  user_webapp (tomcat 6 or 7)
```

Moreover: v2.5 is declared as **javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5** and version v3.0.1 is declared as **javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1**, so there is a difference.

Would it be a problem for **some_framework** to specify different servlet-api dependency (eg 2.5) than defined as provided in mylib (eg 3.0)? I assume that since scope is *provided* (and available only in compile time), dependency tools (mvn, gradle...) will not download it in **some_framework**, and they have (and are allowed) to declare dependency manually.

(yeah, i am aware of differences between 3.0 and 2.5, and that is not a question. I also assume everything compiles correctly, etc. I am just interested how maven would compile **some_framework**, on which dependency: 2.5 or 3?).

Comment: Maven is flexible enough to support any scenario with enough manual configuration if that's what you're asking. If project **X** depends on project **Y**, in `x/pom.xml` I can declare that it should ignore ("exclude") a given dependency from Y. (Which is what I would do were I the author of `some_framework` in your example.) That said if you do not do this explicitly I'm guessing that Maven will simply compile your project against both.

Comment: That said it's not very clear what your question is here, there's a lot of related concepts involved. The JAR version conflict wouldn't be a "problem" as far as Maven is concerned, but it might cause builds to fail. Or it might not, depending on how `javac` handles duplicate classes on the classpath (I believe it's "first one found wins"), and how Maven happens to construct the classpath to begin with.

Comment: @milimoose I do not want to exclude anything manually. Assuming there is no compile error (and why should it be? **some_framework** uses only 2.5, so we are all good). You are guessing Maven will compile using both, or you know that? :) As I assume differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question, as [SO] never helped with tricky ones:)

I created simple maven project (that will act as **some_framework**). It depends on `jodd-servlet` (**mylib**), that has servlets 3.0.1 listed as *provided* dependency. When I run

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

i do not see servlets in the list of dependencies. Now, if current project (i.e. **some_framework**) lists servlets v2.5 as dependency; and then if I run the same command again, I see only dependency on 2.5.

Therefore, we may say that provided dependencies are not transparent or exported.